# Using HashSet to check if a key is pressed

Tags: java, keyboard, keypress, hashset

I have recently been writing a program that has a:

```
public static Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();
```

Now the Set "pressed" is added to like this:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
}
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
            pressed.remove(e.getKeyChar());
}
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    //System.out.println("keyTyped");
}
```

Now if I wanted to do something like

```
pressed.contains(x);
```

Where x was a key on the keyboard, how would I do that. I have tried

```
 pressed.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
```

However it seems that even when I am pressing the up arrow key, the Set "pressed" does not contains the event VK_UP. All I need to know is how to figure out what to enter into the .contains parameter to check if it is in the Set pressed.

Comment: I thought that `KeyEvent.VK_UP` represents an int, not a char, but maybe I'm wrong. Going to check.

Comment: Regardless, for best help, consider creating and posting your [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Where you do

```
public static Set<Character> pressed = new HashSet<Character>();
---
pressed.add(e.getKeyChar());
```

you should be doing

```
public static Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<>();
...
pressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
                    ^^^^
```

Also make the analogous change to the remove code.

The key code is the raw keyboard code that you are comparing to, not the character assigned to the key (not all keys have characters assigned).